# How to create multiple files for writing multiple lists on the fly using Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop

I will try to provide example for the question.

Let's say we have 3 lists. e.g :-

```
list1 =['one','two','three']
list2=['a','b','c']
list3=['mike','jack','ram']
```

Or, say there are list values for each lines in the file.

```
['one','two','three']
['a','b','c']
['mike','jack','ram']
```

Now I want to write the three lists to three different files by creating them. The names of the files should be autogenerated e.g:-

```
file001.txt
file002.txt
file003.txt
```

Comment: Why does simultaneously matter; just open & write one file for each list. Does your real data stream in somehow (wouldn't be a list then)? Is it very large?

Comment: I am guessing your list values are inside one file?? something like ['one','two','three'] and next line ['a','b','c'] ??

Comment: @NickT Yes. I have more than 50 documents that I have parsed into 50 lists. Now I have to write them into 50 files automatically.

Comment: @everestial007 Each list writes into a diiferent file. Like list1 to file001.txt and list2 into file002.txt and so on..

Comment: So, you want to read 50 different files in automated fashion, and each has one line of data.

Comment: I am working on it. letting you know

Comment: If you already have the lists parsed and in memory, just open up files one by one in a loop, you gain nothing by having them all open at the same time.

Comment: @everestial007 Yes. Think of list1 string contents as a line. Similarly for other two lists too.

Comment: Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) to construct the file names.

Comment: So, list1 is a file or variable?

Comment: @everestial007 List1 is a list in python. A Varialble

Comment: So, its not a file. you should be clear on that. ok

Comment: does ```list1``` go *into* ```file001```?

Comment: @wwii Yes. list2 goes to file002 and so on

Comment: How are the list items separated in the file?  one item per line or one line with each item separated by a comma?

Comment: one line with each item

Comment: Check the answer I just put

Comment: @everestial007 Testing now

Comment: I also changed the title and details inside the question a little bit, so it reflected what was really asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that your data is in the console and each list is a line.

**something like this:**

```
line1 =['one','two','three']
line2=['a','b','c']
line3=['mike','jack','ram']
```

**I merged all the data into one lists of list**

```
all_data = [line1] + [line2] + [line3]
```

This above part is not necessary if all the list values are line by line in one variable. If not you can merge them using some method.

**Now, write each line (list values) to the different file:**

```
count = 1

for data in all_data:
    output = open('file' + str(count) + '.txt', 'w')
    output.write(','.join(data))
    count += 1
    output.close()
```

This keeps going on until the last value of the list. So, based on how many lists are there. If you want to join the values inside the list you can change the `''.join` with something desirable in the single quotes (`''`).

Hope I helped.

Comment: This answer is close to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a detailed explanation [here](http://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html) . But to sum it all up ,  you define an object of the type file , by opening a file(or creating one if it doesn't exist) , and then writing / reading / etc...

Comment: What does that have to do with simultaneity?

Answer (score 0):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) to construct the file names.

```
s = 'file{:03}.txt'
for n, lyst in enumerate((list1, list2, list3), 1):
    fname = s.format(n)
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        #f.write(','.join(lyst))
        f.write('\n'.join(lyst))
```

---

If any of the items are not strings change the *write* to

```
        f.write('\n'.join(map(str, lyst)))
```

---

If the lists are so long that creating a single string to write to the file is prohibitive, change the *write* to

```
        for thing in lyst:
            f.write('{}\n'.format(thing))
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to generate as many files as many lines are there. I think the better approach is to read and write each line on the fly.

Comment: @everestial007 - when you think a certain method is *better*, you should say why it is better.

Comment: I was just trying to point out that, if data is read and write by each line (on the fly) it will work not matter how many lines are there (50 or millions).

Comment: @everestial007 - thnx